# Homomorphisms between $\mathbb {F_p}$ and $\mathbb F_{p^2} \bigoplus \mathbb F_p$.

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory, finite-fields, group-homomorphism

I’m looking for a good method to count number of ring homomorphisms between 2 rings $\mathbb {F_p}$ and $\mathbb F_{p^2} \bigoplus \mathbb F_p$. I don’t know how I can find ALL subfields isomorphic to $\mathbb F_p$ in the direct sum and how I can guarantee that no elements of the field have a zero divisor image. Thank you in advance!

Comment: Over which ring are you taking the tensor product?

Comment: I’m taking a direct product (sorry for mistake)

Comment: The symbol $\oplus$ is typically used for direct sums in the category of modules and could be used more generally to refer to direct sums of objects in abelian categories (which the category of rings is not, because it is not additive and not even normal). To denote direct products of rings the correct symbol is $\times$ (in the binary case) or more generally $\Pi$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $A$ be a  ring with $1$. Ring morphisms $\mathbb{F}_p\to A$ are in 1-1 correspondence with ring morphisms $f: \mathbb{Z}\to\ A$ such that $\ker(f)\supset p\mathbb{Z}$.

There is exactly one ring morphism $\theta:\mathbb{Z}\to A$, and it is defined by $\theta (m)=m\cdot 1_A$.

Now $p\in\ker(\theta)$ if and only if $p\cdot 1_A=0$, meaning that $A$ is either trivial or have characteristic $p$.

**Conclusion.** for any  ring with $1$, there is no ring morphism $\mathbb{F}_p\to A$ if $A$ is not trivial has characteristic $\neq p$, and there exists exactly one ring morphism $\mathbb{F}_p\to A$ if $A$ has characteristic $p$.

In particular, the second possibility occurs in your situation.